# Tkinter project to turn pictures to greyscale

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

I have this code which is supposed to reveal the correct version of four images.

To do this I have to turn them into greyscale bitmaps. A greyscale bitmap is    a bitmap where every pixel has red, green and blue values (RGB) which are the same. In order to convert a coloured bitmap to greyscale, each RGB value in the bitmap is set to the same value, the average of its red, green and blue components.

I have this code so far:

```
from tkinter import *

def convert_to_hex(colour_tuple):
    hex_colour_string = "#"
    for rgb in colour_tuple:
        hex_colour_string = hex_colour_string + format(rgb, '02x') 
    return hex_colour_string 

def set_a_pixel_of_bitmap(bitmap_image, colour_tuple, position_tuple):
    hex_colour = convert_to_hex(colour_tuple)
    bitmap_image.put(hex_colour, position_tuple)

def get_a_pixel_colour_tuple(bitmap_image, across, down):
    pixel_colour_values = bitmap_image.get(across, down)

    if type(pixel_colour_values) is str:
        pixel_colour_values = pixel_colour_values.split()
    else:
        pixel_colour_values = list(pixel_colour_values) 

    for i in range(len(pixel_colour_values)):
        pixel_colour_values[i] = int(pixel_colour_values[i])

    return tuple(pixel_colour_values)

def display_bitmap_inside_canvas(a_canvas, an_image, centre_x, centre_y):
    a_canvas.create_image((centre_x, centre_y), image = an_image)
    return an_image

def get_revealed_bitmap(bitmap_image):
    width = bitmap_image.width()
    height = bitmap_image.height()
    for across in range(width):
        for down in range(height):
            a_tuple = get_a_pixel_colour_tuple(bitmap_image, across, down)
            new_list = list(a_tuple)
            if a_tuple[0] < 10 and a_tuple[1] < 10 and a_tuple[2] < 10:
                new_list[0] = ((new_list[0] * 10) + new_list[1] + new_list[2]) / 3
                new_list [0] = new_list [1]
                new_list[1] = new_list[2]
                a_tuple = tuple(new_list)
                set_a_pixel_of_bitmap(bitmap_image, a_tuple, (across ,down))

def from_gif_get_bitmap(gif_filename):
    my_image = PhotoImage(file=gif_filename)
    return my_image

def run_shit(a_canvas):
    positions = [(450, 450), (150, 150), (450, 150), (150, 450)]
    images = []
    for selection in range(1, 5):
        current_image_name = "PhotoImage" + str(selection)
        current_image = from_gif_get_bitmap(current_image_name)
        current_image = get_revealed_bitmap(current_image)  #2
        centre_tuple = positions[selection % len(positions)]
        display_bitmap_inside_canvas(a_canvas, current_image, centre_tuple[0], centre_tuple[1])  #3
        images.append(current_image)

    return images

def main():
    window = Tk() 
    window.title("Testing stuff")
    window.geometry("600x600+10+20")
    a_canvas = Canvas(window)
    a_canvas.config(background="blue")
    a_canvas.pack(fill=BOTH, expand = True)
    a_canvas.pack()
    image_list = run_shit(a_canvas)
    window.mainloop()

main()
```

This is supposed to print out 4 different images all in greyscale. For example:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/2jaRx.jpg

But I just get a plain blue background without the images being shown. I don't get any errors either. Just need to know where I'm going wrong.

I would appreciate someone spotting out my errors and helping me fix them.

Comment: use `print()` to check values in variables or learn how to use debuger.

Comment: `set_a_pixel_of_bitmap` doesn't return value (so it return `None`) but you use returned value as `correct greyscale`. better use `print()` to check other variables.

Comment: Alright thank you for pointing this out. I changed it so that it returns the bitmap image instead. I got this now: http://imgur.com/a/O4ANx.

Comment: `return bitmap_image` has wrong indention.

Comment: now I see you don't need to assign value in  `bitmap_image = set_a_...`. Run `set_a_..` without `bitmap_image = `

Comment: Still get a blue background only.

Comment: run `get_revealed_bitmap()` without  `current_image =`. `get_revealed_bitmap` works on oryginal image and returns `None` . You say ` average of its red, green and blue components.` but I don't see this in your code. Your code gets pixel from image and puts in image the same pixel.

Comment: I changed it so that it gets the average and then makes it the same for all components. I still don't understand why it doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

I changed almost everything - starting at too long names - and I got this:

```
import tkinter as tk


def convert_to_greyscale(image, method=3):

    for x in range(image.width()):
        for y in range(image.height()):

            pixel = image.get(x, y)

            if method in (0, 1, 2): # R or G or B
                val = pixel[method]
                pixel = (val, val, val)
            elif method == 3:   # average
                val = sum(pixel)//3
                pixel = (val, val, val)
            #else:              # without changes
            #   pixel = pixel

            image.put('#%02x%02x%02x' % pixel, (x, y))


def add_images(canvas):

    positions = [(450, 450), (150, 150), (450, 150), (150, 450)]
    images = []

    for index, pos in enumerate(positions, 1):

        image = tk.PhotoImage(file="PhotoImage%i.gif" % index)

        convert_to_greyscale(image) #(image, index-1)

        canvas.create_image(pos, image=image)

        images.append(image) 

    return images


def main():
    window = tk.Tk() 
    window.title("Testing stuff")
    window.geometry("600x600+10+20")

    canvas = tk.Canvas(window)
    canvas.config(background="blue")
    canvas.pack(fill=tk.BOTH, expand=True)

    images = add_images(canvas)

    window.mainloop()

main()
```

(tested only on one .gif file so remove extension in code)

As default it gets `"average of R,G,B"` but it can also gets `"only R"` or `"only G"` or `"only B"` (for methods 0, 1, 2)

Comment: I really don't want to change the functions I have. Just want to find the problem in my code. Thank you for the help regardless.

Comment: sorry I tried to find problem in your code but there was many annyoing elements (like long names or `display_bitmap` which run only one command) so I started to remove them  to find real problem. This way I created my version.

Answer (score 0):

```
from tkinter import *

def convert_to_hex(colour_tuple):
    hex_colour_string = "#"
    for rgb in colour_tuple:
        hex_colour_string = hex_colour_string + format(rgb, '02x') 
    return hex_colour_string 

def set_a_pixel_of_bitmap(bitmap_image, colour_tuple, position_tuple):
    hex_colour = convert_to_hex(colour_tuple)
    bitmap_image.put(hex_colour, position_tuple)

def get_a_pixel_colour_tuple(bitmap_image, across, down):
    pixel_colour_values = bitmap_image.get(across, down)

    if type(pixel_colour_values) is str:
        pixel_colour_values = pixel_colour_values.split()
    else:
        pixel_colour_values = list(pixel_colour_values) 

    for i in range(len(pixel_colour_values)):
        pixel_colour_values[i] = int(pixel_colour_values[i])

    return tuple(pixel_colour_values)

def display_bitmap_inside_canvas(a_canvas, an_image, centre_x, centre_y):
    a_canvas.create_image((centre_x, centre_y), image = an_image)
    return an_image

def get_revealed_bitmap(bitmap_image):
    width = bitmap_image.width()
    height = bitmap_image.height()
    highest_value = 256
    for across in range(width):
        for down in range(height):
            a_tuple = get_a_pixel_colour_tuple(bitmap_image, across, down)
            new_list = list(a_tuple)
            if a_tuple[0] < highest_value and a_tuple[1] < highest_value and a_tuple[2] < highest_value:
                red = new_list[0]
                new_red = min(255, red * 10)
                new_list[0] = new_red
                new_list[1] = new_list[0]
                new_list[2] = new_list[0]
                a_tuple = tuple(new_list)
                set_a_pixel_of_bitmap(bitmap_image, a_tuple, (across ,down))
    return bitmap_image

def from_gif_get_bitmap(gif_filename):
    my_image = PhotoImage(file=gif_filename)
    return my_image

def run_shit(a_canvas):
    positions = [(450, 450), (150, 150), (450, 150), (150, 450)]
    images = []
    for selection in range(1, 5):
        current_image_name = "PhotoImage" + str(selection)
        current_image = from_gif_get_bitmap(current_image_name)
        current_image = get_revealed_bitmap(current_image)  #2
        centre_tuple = positions[selection % len(positions)]
        display_bitmap_inside_canvas(a_canvas, current_image, centre_tuple[0], centre_tuple[1])  #3
        images.append(current_image)

    return images

def main():
    window = Tk() 
    window.title("Testing stuff")
    window.geometry("600x600+10+20")
    a_canvas = Canvas(window)
    a_canvas.config(background="blue")
    a_canvas.pack(fill=BOTH, expand = True)
    a_canvas.pack()
    image_list = run_shit(a_canvas)
    window.mainloop()

main()
```

I made a little mistake but this seems to work.